# Script: Invalid username and permissions denied

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, password

I am trying to write a script that creates multiple users from a text file and then add them to the group I created called "interns". I want to set a default password of "AIST2330PASSWORD" and then prompt the users to change the password when they log in. The code I have now is

```
for i in $(cat users.txt)
do
echo useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G interns $i
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G interns $i
echo "AIST2330PASSWORD" | passwd --stdin $i
passwd -e $i
echo "User needs to chnage pw upon reentry"
done
```

The errors I get are:

```
paaswd: Permission denied.
User needs to change pw upon reentry
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -G interns hmccoy
'seradd: invalid user name 'hmccoy 
passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error `passwd: unrecognized option '--stdin'` because there is no such option as `--stdin` to give passwords using `passwd` command via STDIN in Ubuntu.

You can not pass passwords non-interactively using `passwd` command, while in interactive shell `passwd` uses STDIN to take password. This only happens for interactive operations, if you are using shell procedures such as piping, it won't work.

As you are looking to create batch users with the same password for all, perhaps you should look at `newusers` command that would exactly suffice in your case.